# How to specify symbol position on the marker?

Tags: qt, qwt

I am using `Qwt` library. I have added vertical `QwtPlotMarker` on the plot. I want to add `QwtSymbol` to my `marker` and I want the `symbol` to be in the bottom of the `marker`. When I use `setSymbol()` it places symbol in the middle of the marker. There are `setLabelAlignment()` function to specify where the label is drawn. Unfortunately, I did not found anything like that for `symbol`. I have read  [Qwt User's Guide](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_marker.html#af44231c2b63bb277706e4f515297c7b1) where I found: `The setSymbol() member assigns a symbol to the marker. The symbol is drawn at the specified point.` So, how to specify that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very old question, but I found solution and I want to share with you.

There is way to specify this point. Method setValue(double x, double y) do this, but this method not describes in the documentation (it's very strange for me), but this method works!

I wrote small but useful snippet. If I understand you correctly, this code do exactly what you need

```
   QwtSymbol *sym=new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Diamond,QBrush(Qt::red),QPen(Qt::red),QSize(5,5));
   //create the symbol
   QwtPlotMarker *mark=new QwtPlotMarker;
        mark->setSymbol(sym);

        mark->setLineStyle(QwtPlotMarker::VLine);
        //set vertical line

        mark->setValue(5,ui->qwtPlot->axisInterval(QwtPlot::yLeft).minValue());
        //here you have to set the coordinate axis i.e. where the axis are meeting.
        //as you can see I set coordinate 5 and the lowest coordinate of Y axis
        //you can set here needed coordinates

        mark->attach(ui->qwtPlot);
```

I hope, it helps.